# my program is skipping one symbol scanf, but the rest are not skipped

Tags: c

When I try to run the code. The output in the terminal tries to skip the symbol. I don't know why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int rows;
    int columns;
    char symbol;
    printf("\nEnter # of rows: ");
    scanf("%d", &rows);
    printf("Enter # of columns: ");
    scanf("%d", &columns); 
    printf("Enter a symbol to use: ");
    scanf("%c", &symbol);

    for(int i = 1; i <= rows; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 1; j <= columns; j++)
        {
            printf("%s",  &symbol);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The terminal output:

```
Enter # of rows: 2
Enter # of columns: 3
Enter a symbol to use:
```

Comment: Unlike most other formats, `%c` does *not* skip leading white-space (like the newline from the previous input).

Comment: @Elias,  `printf("%s",  &symbol);` is bad as `"%s"` matches a pointer to a _string_.  `&symbol` does not point to a _string_, but to a single `char` with the value of `'\n'`.

Comment: consider checking the return values of ```scanf``` and the fact that using ```scanf``` to read ```int``` will make your code vulnerable to integer overflows since ```scanf``` does not prevent it.

Comment: To elaborate on the previous comment by @chux: Using `printf` with the `%s` conversion format specifier requires that you pass a pointer to a null-terminated string. However, you are instead passing a pointer to a single `char`, so the "string" probably is not null-terminated. Therefore, your program is invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). In order to print a single character, you can use the `%c` conversion specifier instead of `%s`, or you can use the function [`putchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/putchar) instead of `printf`.

Comment: You can put a space before the %c in the format string to eat the '\n' which remains in the keyboard buffer: `scanf(" %c", &symbol);`